# How can I get the ID from an image from camera or internal storage to put into Android EasySlider?

Tags: java, android

I'm programming a new app for my city and I need help with some code. I'm using the EasySliders library for Android, and I need to put images taken from either the camera or internal storage.

I could put them in ImageViews, but I want to put them into a slider. EasySlider needs 2 parameters:

1. A title for the image
2. An ID

How can I get the id from those pictures?

```
Bitmap bitmap;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dir);

// Here is the problem, the bitmap is not an id and it causes an error
easySliders.add(new SliderItem("temporalname", bitmap));
```